Index.html file disappearing on a Microsoft Azure Deployment for a Web Application
It seems the index.html file for my web application is disappearing on deployment to MS Azure. I know this sounds strange, as how could the application start without it? But, when I open the Safari debugger and look at the source files, index.html is missing, and I am getting an error (null) in my JavaScript code that is doing a getElementByName on a html fragment that is in this index.html file.
What could be going wrong here?
Within Azure, I set the deployment type to Custom.
And I set the root to /. I do not have my source files in a subdirectory within my Github Repository.
Static Web App. No framework used. Just HTML and JavaScript.
Error:
Error: Could not find either 'build' or 'build:azure' node under 'scripts' in package.json. Could not find value for custom run build command using the environment variable key 'RUN_BUILD_COMMAND'.Could not find tools for building monorepos, no 'lerna.json' or 'lage.config.js' files found. – 

Oryx could not find a 'build' or 'build:azure' script in the package configuration. Please add one of these commands to your package configuration file (i.e. package.json). Alternatively, you can add the app_build_command to the build/deploy section of your workflow file. For example, app_build_command: 'npm run docs:build'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Are you deploying to Azure Web App or Static web app?

What is the framework of your app node or react ?

Static Web App.  No framework used.  Just HTML and JavaScript.

Provide complete error logs.

Error: Could not find either 'build' or 'build:azure' node under 'scripts' in package.json. Could not find value for custom run build command using the environment variable key 'RUN_BUILD_COMMAND'.Could not find tools for building monorepos, no 'lerna.json' or 'lage.config.js' files found.

Oryx could not find a 'build' or 'build:azure' script in the package configuration. Please add one of these commands to your package configuration file (i.e. package.json). Alternatively, you can add the app_build_command to the build/deploy section of your workflow file. For example, app_build_command: 'npm run docs:build'

Html app didn't need package.json file.

If your project folder contains a package.json, file delete it.

Please edit the question with the details provided in the comments.


Error: Could not find either 'build' or 'build:azure' node under 'scripts' in package.json. Could not find value for custom run build command using the environment variable key 'RUN_BUILD_COMMAND'.Could not find tools for building monorepos, no 'lerna.json' or 'lage.config.js' files found. –
Oryx could not find a 'build' or 'build:azure' script in the package configuration. Please add one of these commands to your package configuration file (i.e. package.json). Alternatively, you can add the app_build_command to the build/deploy section of your workflow file. For example, app_build_command: 'npm run docs:build'

Even I got the Same Issue When I added the package.json file to the root directory.
Because Azure Static Web app use Oryx build engine to detect and process the deployment. It looks for certain files for configuration.
If it detects the package.json file it assumes that the app is node or react, angular, next app that requires build step and looks for build script in package.json.
I deleted the package.json file because the HTML app doesn't require a build process. Oryx now assumes it is a static web app.
Below is my Complete GitHub Workflow File.
GitHub Workflow File:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_KIND_MUD_0E1E6DE0F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/" 
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "." 
  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_KIND_MUD_0E1E6DE0F }}
          action: "close"

Azure Output:


Hi Aslesha, I do not have a package.json file in my GitHub Repo.

What should my build type be for a Static Web App?  Should it be Custom or should it be Html?  My Web App has Javascript and some libraries. I was using Custom in the past, and it worked.  Not it doesn't. It seems Microsoft like to change things, and not inform anyone about it.

@user1104028 Try with html.

@user1104028 I also used custom it works fine for me.

@user1104028 Check the GitHub repository once the error is related to package.json.

@user1104028 Try Build Presets : Html while creating static web app.

There is no package.json file at the root level.  However, there is a package.json file within a subdirectory of a sound library I am using called, "howler."

@user1104028 If possible, share your complete project structure.

@user1104028 If it is unnecessary, remove the package.json file in the subdirectory.
